# Pluralisation when describing multiple objects simultaenously

Tags: notation, terminology

An example is:

Let $f_i : X \rightarrow Y, f_i(x) = y_i,\text{ for all } i$ be a function.

or

Let $f_i : X \rightarrow Y, f_i(x) = y_i,\text{ for all } i$ be functions.

To me the first case seems to be more natural but since we're describing multiple functions at once, just under an umbrella, it could also be the case that the second case is correct instead.

($\textit{Better tags would be appreciated.}$)

Comment: Do you mean $f_i(x)$?

Comment: That is indeed what I meant (edited as appropriate).

Comment: I'm under the impression that the first refers to *one* multi-dimensional function, while the second refers to a sequence of functions. They both seem to make sense, and in deed can be used interchangeably unless specified in a broader context, I think.

Comment: What about "Let (...) be a collection of functions." or sonething similar?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, both were helpful. If someone wants to add their answer as a response I can go ahead and select a best answer and upvote the other one (when my limit is back).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say either of the following:

For each $i$, let $f_{i}:X \to Y$ be a function

or

Let $f_{i}: X \to Y$ $(i=1,2\ldots)$ be a sequence of functions.